# Python delete file if it has a specific size in bytes

Tags: python, automation

Basically trying to go over some 1000+ files in a folder, and delete any of duplicate sizes. My method was to loop through the whole folder in one go, deleting and files that have an exact byte size that has been seen in a previous file.

I've tried writing it in various ways to get it to work, but I keep ending up at the same error that it cannot find the file specified, and lists the name of the file it is on.

```
import os

def cleanup():
    sizes = [1,2,3] #in bytes

    for fileName in os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Jake\Desktop\testing"): #iterate through all items in directory
        fileDIR = (r"C:\Users\Jake\Desktop\testing" + "\\" + fileName)
        fileSize = os.path.getsize(fileDIR) # get integer value size in bytes of the file

        for i in sizes: #compare the size of the current focused file to the items in the list
            if fileSize == i:
                os.remove(fileName) #If the filesize has been seen before, delete the given file. If not, add the size and go on to next file.
            else:
                sizes.append(fileSize)

cleanup()
```

Comment: Can you add the error you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is to do with how you're iterating over your `sizes` list.

For every `file` you find, you're iterating over the entire list, and appending the size multiple times.

`for i in sizes:` will cause you to iterate even after the file has matched and been deleted, if it encounters the size before the end of the list.

You can change this, by just checking if the `size` is found `in` `sizes`.

```
sizes = []

for filename in os.listdir(r"c:\users\admin\storage\\"):
    file = r"c:\users\admin\storage\\" + filename

    size = os.path.getsize(file)

    if size in sizes:
        print('same size', filename)
    else:
        sizes.append(size)
```

The first time i run this on my own folder, it returns;

```
same size static
same size storage

sizes

#[0, 4096, 135168, 554, 102]
```

This matches correctly, as `static` and `storage` are 0 bytes. When i run it again, without modifying the result in `sizes` every file matches.

```
same size .ebextensions
same size customer
same size db.sqlite3
same size manage.py
same size requirements.txt
same size static
same size storage
```